# xmlhttp.responseText validation within Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

My Below javascript is getting resopnse from servlet, when I try to validate, it is working. It is not able to validate the if statement `if (xmlhttp.responseText=="1234")`.

What may be the reason

```
function handleServletPost() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "1234") {
                alert("you are star");
            } else {
                alert("alert-->" + xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Ajax calling error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `===` instead of `==`

Comment: This is trivial to solve yourself. Step through your code with a debugger and see what `xmlhttp.responseText` is.

Comment: alert `xmlhttp.responseText`, what do you see?

Comment: As mentioned above, `console.log` or `alert` the value of `xmlhttp.responseText` and see if it really is `'1234'`

Comment: @Cruncher If `==` doesn't work, what makes you think `===` might?

Comment: @Kolink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/javascript-string-equality-whats-the-correct-way this does.

Comment: @Cruncher Well your interpretation of that is wrong. `a === b` cannot be true if `a == b` is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlhttp.responseText brings the space, so we need to trim the value.

Since trim does nto support in plain javascript, I have used jquery to achieve this.