# iMacros iimPlay javascript

Tags: firefox, if-statement, imacros

I'm created two variables that play different iimPlay functions. However, the code always execute the first if statement and ignore the 2nd statement.

**Main.js**

```
var ReturnCode = iimPlay("win.iim");  
var returncode2 = iimPlay("lose.iim"); //
if (ReturnCode = 1) {         *//when returncode =1 means complete execute*
iimPlay("reset.iim");
} 

if (returncode2 = 1 ) {
iimPlay("double.iim");
}
```

**Win.iim**

```
IMAGESEARCH POS=1 IMAGE=C:\win.png CONFIDENCE=65
```

> *imagesearch will always execute no matter match or not*

**Lose.iim**

```
IMAGESEARCH POS=1 IMAGE=C:\lose.png CONFIDENCE=65
```

> *imagesearch will always execute no matter match or not*

**HTML tag**

```
<div id="game-result" class="balance-change fail">
<span id="result-text">
LOST
</span> </div>
```

Problem : Whenever the iimPlay("win.iim") detects win or lose image, it still execute the first statement as fact that lose image should execute the second if statement.

Comment: without seeing win.iim code it is impossible to understand the problem you have

Comment: Put alert(""); after each iimPlay. When you get prompt you will be able to see error message in the Display. Maybe you have some kind of error.

Comment: @Bestmacros Content updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using image search try with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:image_you_are_looking_for CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER


TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV  ATTR=CLASS:second_image_you_are_looking_for CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

This way will return error code if it's not present.

And also this is the error.

```
if (returncode2 = 1 ) { }
```

You are setting value 1 into returncode2 not comparing it to 1. The correct is

```
if (returncode2 == 1 ) { }
```

Even better is:

```
if (returncode2 > 0 ) { }
```

Same for the other return code. Fix these and try again.

Comment: When I saw the win's image, it doesn't execute the both if statements, just jump to end of code line. I already used '==' and '>', but problem still remain. The win.iim does not show error, but lose.iim does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be always careful with the `EQUAL` sign. In Javascript for comparasion you use `==` or `===`. Your code does an attribution and will always be `TRUE`; that's why it is always executed. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/javascript-string-equality-whats-the-correct-way) for details about javascript equality.