# how to compare the 2 string by ignoring the end of string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a variable in Jquery like following:

```
   var var1="3com.rsmart.certification.impl.hibernate.criteria.gradebook.GreaterThanScoreCriterionHibernateImpl";
```

Now I have one more string like

```
 var var2="3com.rsmart.certification.criteria.impl.gradebook.GreaterThanScoreCriteriaTemplate";
```

Now i want to comapre both the string by considering upto certain stage

```
    3com.rsmart.certification.criteria.impl.gradebook.GreaterThanScoreCriteri
```

so can one help me out,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: `var1.indexOf(searchStr) === 0 && var2.indexOf(searchStr) === 0`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking - the string you search for does not appear in var1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Example usage for your case

```
var compareLength = 10; // depends on your situation
if (var1.substring(0,compareLength)===var2.substring(0,compareLenth)) {
.
.
.
}
```

Why we use "===" is here. 
[What is the correct way to check for string equality in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/javascript-string-equality-whats-the-correct-way)

Also you can add a generic function to your client javascript page like this:

```
String.prototype.compareLeft=function(compareWith,len){
    return this.substring(0,len)===compareWith.substring(0,len)
}
```

And then in anywhere of your script (after defining function) you can use:

```
var compareLength = 10; // depends on your situation
if (var1.compareLeft(var2,compareLength)) {
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript [test](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) method and regular expression, Try this

```
     var var1="3com.rsmart.certification.impl.hibernate.criteria.gradebook.GreaterThanScoreCriterionHibernateImpl";
    var var2="3com.rsmart.certification.criteria.impl.gradebook.GreaterThanScoreCriteriaTemplate";
    var patt = /3com.rsmart.certification.impl.hibernate.criteria.gradebook.GreaterThanScoreCriteri/i;
    if(patt.test(var1)==patt.test(var2)){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the two character by character.

```
var max = Math.min(left.length, right.length);
for (var i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    if (left.charAt(i) != right.charAt(i))
        return left.substring(0, i);
return left.substring(0, max);
```