# TypeScript: correct way to do string equality?

Tags: typescript

If I know x and y are both of type string, is the correct way to do string equality simply x == y?

The linter I'm using complains about this.

Comment: What does the linter say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript String Equality... What's the correct way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/javascript-string-equality-whats-the-correct-way)

Answer (score 93):

If you know `x` and `y` are both strings, using `===` is not strictly necessary, but is still good practice.

Assuming both variables actually are strings, both operators will function identically. However, TS often allows you to pass an object that meets all the requirements of `string` rather than an actual string, which may complicate things.

Given the possibility of confusion or changes in the future, your linter is probably correct in demanding `===`. Just go with that.

Answer (score 5):

Use below code for string comparison

```
if(x === y) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score -23):

The `===` is not for checking string equalit , to do so you can use the Regxp functions for example

```
if (x.match(y) === null) {
// x and y are not equal 
}
```

there is also the `test` function

Comment: @Brain Well, I think that the opening statement is directly wrong. You can absolutely check for (string) equality with `===`. And the tagged "possible duplicate answer" as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) goes much into detail on comparisons. None of them suggests using `.match()`