# Loop through Controls to validate password match

Tags: angular, ionic2

Am a bit stuck with this as ControlGroup no longer exists.

I have to check that two password match on the front end.

```
 this.updatePassordForm = _form.group({
        matchingPassword: _form.group({
            password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$")]),
            confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
        }, { validator: this.areEqual })
    })
```

How can I validate that the passwords are equal by looping through the controls?

```
  areEqual(group:any) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should extract the values from your form group:

```
this.updatePassordForm.controls['matchingPassword'].controls['password'].value 
this.updatePassordForm.controls['matchingPassword'].controls['confirmPassword'].value
```

2) You should check if two values are equal using ===. It is not necessary but still a good practice [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770484/typescript-correct-way-to-do-string-equality)