# if(array.length===1) condition not working for array of length > 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an `if-else` within my main controller:

```
var entity = shareDataService.getModalEntity();

if (entity = "NULL" || entity.length === 1) {
    myDataPromise = getDataService.getDataFromREST(security);
    console.log("HERE")
} else {
    myDataPromise = $q.all(getDataService.keepICorrect(security));
    console.log("THERE")
};
```

It takes `entities` data from a service, `shareDataService`.

It works fine when `entity.length === 1`  or `entity === "NULL"`, but when the array is of `length` 2 or more, the condition does not pass it to the `else`.  I cannot work out for the life of my why, I have debugged just before the `if-else` to check the value passed to the controller's function, and the array is definitely of `length` 2+ when I intend it to be.  Also debugging `entity.length` just before the `if-else` shows the correct length of the array.  What am I  missing?

Comment: typo ! entity == "NULL"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to check for string equality in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-string-equality-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assigning values intead of comparing

```
entity = "NULL"
```

Try like this

```
entity == "NULL"
```

**Sugession** :

You can check **[falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)** .

`null`,`''`,`undefined`,`0`,`NaN` consider **[falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)** in javascript

Try like this

```
if(!entity || entity.length === 1)
```

Comment: @Sulthan not if comparing to a string

Comment: Bingo.  How did I miss this.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: Just to reiterate, "==" if string, "===" for all else?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the actual string "NULL" needs to be used if no array is detected, if a string is passed as "NULL" is it only a string or can it be considered falsy?

Comment: @Nope "NULL" is not equal to null

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thanks @AnikIslamAbhi

Answer (score 1):

```
var entity = shareDataService.getModalEntity();

if (entity = "NULL" || entity.length === 1) {
```

Note the `=` instead of `==` or `===`, you're **assigning** a value of `"null"` to `entity` which then evaluates to a truthy value, the `||` is short-circuiting so because the first expression evaluates to truthy the `length === 1` part won't be evaluated, so the true branch of the `if` statement will always be executed.