# Comparing Strings in an IF statement

Tags: javascript

The country_code in this case can be DE or GB.

```
var cc = country_code

if (cc.equals == "GB"){
    console.log("You're in the UK")
  }
  else {
    console.log("You're not in the UK")
}
```

Why is this statement throwing up incorrect responses?

EDIT:

The missing " was a typo.
The solutions given haven't work so far.

I set country_code to be the text response of a XMLHttpRequest object.
If that helps?

Comment: Don't need `.equals`, use `cc === "GB"`. `console.log(You're not in the UK")` Missing start quote, `"`.

Comment: is country code is object or you are comparing wrong ? I highly doubt in this line if @Tushar comment is just a typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to check for string equality in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-string-equality-in-javascript)

Comment: @Tushar that should be an answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell What about dupe

Comment: @Tushar given that it's both an incorrect comparison and a syntax error, it isn't quite covered by the dupe. I'd say it's worth answering.

Comment: what is `cc` here? is it string?

Comment: cc is the text response of a XMLHttpRequest object

Comment: How are the given solutions failing? What output are they giving and what errors are they causing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this was happening was because the text response from my XMLHttpRequest object was actually "GB " - three characters long.

I just cut it down to two and it worked fine:
cc.substring(0,2)

Answer (score 2):

You must use the [Equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) (`==`) [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) to check if the value of `cc` is equal to the string literal `"GB"`. Or you can use the [Strict equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) (`===`) operator to see if the operands are equal and of the same type.

Also the argument to the `console.log` call in the `else` branch must be within quotation marks, or else you'll get syntax error. String literals must always be enclosed in `'` or `"`.

```
var cc = country_code;

if (cc == "GB"){
    console.log("You're in the UK")
}
else {
    console.log("You're not in the UK")
}
```

Comment: you can also suggest strict checking with `===`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Good point. I've updated my answer to go into further detail in regard to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

> The country_code in this case can be DE or GB.

That means the variable `country_code` is a **string**.

So, `cc.equals == "GB"` will return `undefined` as there is no member property `equals` on the String prototype.

To compare two strings use [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) `==` or [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) `===`.

```
if (cc === "GB") {
```

Also, in the `else` block, there is missing quote.
It should be

```
console.log("You're not in the UK")
            ^
```

Here's complete code:

```
var cc = country_code;

if (cc === "GB") { // Use equality operator to compare strings
    console.log("You're in the UK");
} else {
    console.log("You 're not in the UK"); // Added missing quote
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cc = country_code;

    if (cc == "GB"){
        console.log("You're in the UK");
    }
    else {
        console.log("You're not in the UK");
    }
```