# Javascript equality comparison not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone explain why the line `Logger.log("%s EQUALS %s",col1[i],col2[i]);` is never called? Im new to Javascript, but based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-string-equality-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1) I am using the correct operator for comparison in the `if` statement. The values are guaranteed to be either integers, or an empty cell if that makes a difference.

```
function SetFilter(){
  var first_row_to_hide=4;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var maxrows=sheet.getMaxRows();
  col1 = sheet.getRange(first_row_to_hide,3,maxrows,1).getValues();//getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) -- column: C
  col2 = sheet.getRange(first_row_to_hide,4,maxrows,1).getValues();//column: D
  for (var i = 1; i < col1.length; i++){
    Logger.log("%s ? %s",col1[i],col2[i]);
    if (col1[i] === col2[i]){
     Logger.log("%s EQUALS %s",col1[i],col2[i]); 
    }//sheet.hideRows(i+first_row_to_hide);
  }
  Logger.log("DONE");
}
```

example values in column1 and 2:

```
col1 col2 Log output of '%s ? %s'
1    2    [1.0] ? [2.0]
1    1    [1.0] ? [1.0]
0    0    [0.0] ? [0.0]
0    1    [0.0] ? [0.0]
4    5    [4.0] ? [5.0]
```

Comment: *"Can someone explain why the line ... is never called?"* ~ yes, because `col1[i]` and `col2[i]` are never [identical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity)

Comment: What gets logged by `%s ? %s`?

Comment: could you please add the value of `col1[i]` & `col2[i]`. Also, the strict equality operator needs the type of both operands to be the same.

Comment: Adding to @Agalo's comment, if they are objects, they must be the exact same object reference. Perhaps try `col1[i] == col2[i]` if you're only interested in comparing the values

Comment: @Phil, I tried it both ways, using `==` and `===` before I posted here, thanks for the additional explanation tho... I didn't know that!

Comment: @Agalo, I updated my code with sample values for each column.

Comment: Data retrieved by "setValues()" is 2 dimensional Array. How about a change from col1[i] === col2[i] to col1[i][0] === col2[i][0]?

Comment: @Ryan I updated my code to show the log output, thanks for the suggestion- I should have had it there from the beginning.

Comment: Next time, please read the fine manual ~ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike that solved my problem..... never thought of the array being 2D

Comment: @Tanaike could you post your comment as a solution so I can accept it and resolve this question?

Comment: @Rilcon42 Thank you for your concern. I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"setValues()" has 2 dimensional Array. So your script works by changing

from :

```
if (col1[i] === col2[i]){
 Logger.log("%s EQUALS %s",col1[i],col2[i]); 
}//sheet.hideRows(i+first_row_to_hide);
```

to :

```
if (col1[i][0] === col2[i][0]){
 Logger.log("%s EQUALS %s",col1[i],col2[i]); 
}//sheet.hideRows(i+first_row_to_hide);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the strict comparison `===` which is only true if the operands are of the same type AND the contents are identical (where objects are concerned they must be referencing the exact same object).

Whereas the abstract comparison `==` converts the operands to the same type before comparing.

Likely `col1[i]` and `col2[i]` violate one of the above mentioned conditions.  (in the event they are objects, `==` will also return false unless they reference the same object)

[MDN Comparison operator documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: That makes sense, but they are both columns of integers (see my updated example above). Could I be missing something else, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Bit of a side note, but as strange as it sounds javascript technically doesn't have integers - the type would show up as 'number'.  You can check the types of your variables by using the 'typeof' operator.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Looks like you got it solved in the comments above!  - but checking the types could help prevent such confusion in the future.