# str_replace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to do str_replace in javascript but without using an inbuilt function.
I want Scratch Code for this.

Please Someone can have the code for this? 
I WANT JAVASCRIPT INBUILt FUNCTION STR_REPLACE DITTO without USING STR_REPLACE.

```
function Replace(string, charToChange, charToReplace){
var replaced = "";
for(var i=0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(string[i] == charToChange){
        replaced = charToReplace;
    } 
}
return replaced;
}
```

Comment: Use `"I am joking".split("I am").join("We are");`

Comment: @LGSon,
I can't use any inbuilt Methods....

Comment: Then you simply write your own parser

Comment: smells like homework. what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz Can't agree more....:)

Comment: wait sending Code

Answer (score 0):

JS has a function for replace. go through this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: thanks for reply,
But i want WITHOUT USING STR_REPLACE method

Answer (score 0):

Try the below example

enter code here

```
    function myFunction() 
           {
              var str1 = 'This is a test string.';
            // Let's replace the word This with 'that'
             str1 = str1.split('This').join('that');   
        }
```

Note : The string inside the split function is case sensitive.
Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```js
var string = "abc Code Snippet abc pqr abc";
var result = string.split(' ');
var i =0;
result.forEach(function(element){
if(result[i] == "abc"){
result[i] = "change";
}
i++;
});
var a = result.join(" "); 
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following is entirely under the assumption that you can't use built in functions which is stated by OP in comments

```
function Replace(s, strOld, strNew){
    //find returns the starting index of the string you are looking for
    // do some exception handling or return -1 if not there
    var loc = find(s, strOld); //you should implement find
    //assuming you can't use the slice function
    retStr = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < loc; i++){
        retStr += s[i]; //builds new string with chars up to loc
    }
    retStr += strNew; //put the new string in
    for(var i = loc + strOld.length; i < s.length; i++){
        retStr += s[i]; //puts remaining chars from original string
    }
    return retStr;

}
```

Do something like this. I left the find function up to you but the rest is a pretty simple algorithm. Find should check s by character for matches with strOld that happen in a row.

Note: I changed the variable names from your original function. string to s because it's bad form to name a variable after a type. I changed the other two because they are misleading, since you are trying to replace a string not a char.

I'd also recommend you use `===` instead of `==` for equality until you understand what the difference is. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-string-equality-in-javascript) for more