# Javascript checking if two values are equal using == not working

Tags: javascript

I have this JSON file from which I am extracting a value:

```
var sta = req.jsonBody.sta   //where req.jsonBody.sta = open
```

So according to this my var sta should be equal to open. Now when I do this:

```
var turnOn = true
var open = "open"
if (sta == open)
{
    turnOn = false
    console.log(sta)
}

console.log(turnOn)
```

The value of `turnOn` should be false but my console is printing `true`. I don't now where i am wrong.

Comment: which `console.log` statement is printing `true`.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Are you doing ajax request to get the json file?

Comment: @gurvinder372 The first in the if clause can only print `"open"` but then the second would print `false`

Comment: Try output your `req.jsonBody.sta` with `console.log`.. does it give "open" value?

Comment: Check this Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-string-equality-in-javascript#3586781

Comment: @StefansArya Yes it gives as open

Comment: Chances are the `==` operator is working fine. Saying it is not working conveys no information. See comment from @Andreas

Comment: Can @traktor53 you please reframe the question as I am not able ti find a appropriate title for it

Comment: You have posed an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Start with the assumption made in the first line of code, in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it seems working.

```js
req = {jsonBody:{sta:'open'}};

var sta = req.jsonBody.sta;

var turnOn = true;
var open = "open";
console.log('turnOn = '+turnOn);
if (sta == open)
{
    turnOn = false;
    //console.log(sta);
}
console.log('sta = '+sta);
console.log('turnOn = '+turnOn);
```

Until you have wrong data, like space , which looks like `open` but actually have `open`

```js
req = {jsonBody:{sta:'open '}};

var sta = req.jsonBody.sta;

var turnOn = true;
var open = "open";
console.log('turnOn = '+turnOn);
if (sta == open)
{
    turnOn = false;
    //console.log(sta);
}
console.log('sta = '+sta);
console.log('turnOn = '+turnOn);
```

Comment: @Andreas : I wanted to focus on data like `open` != `open `

Comment: @Andreas : Agreed

Comment: @Andreas everything was working. The problem was just an extra space