# JavaScript issue: cant understand why my code doesnt work

Tags: javascript

Im new to js and I have an issue,

This code works perfectly fine:

```
function test(args){

    return "12345 - "+args;
}

console.log(test("678910"));
```

But this code doesn't:

```
function test(args){
    if(args = ""){
    
    }
    return "12345 - "+args;
}
console.log(test("678910"));
```

[args] becomes undefined for some reason and I cant understand why, I suppose it has something to do with context, but I still dont understand why nothing works, help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `if(args = ""){` you're assigning `args` to an empty string here. You need to use `==` or `===` for comparison

Comment: Why args becomes undefined after this code is main thing that bothers me

Comment: When I run your code `args` does **not** become undefined, it gets set to an empty string, which is due to your if-statement (`args = ""`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to check for string equality in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-string-equality-in-javascript)

Comment: I knew the difference between == and =, i just didnt notice my mistake, thanks to you all again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`. `args = ""` is *assigning* `args` to an empty string, not comparing it.  So you should use:

```
if(args == ""){
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `==` in the if statement and also you have to make it do something if `args == ""`

```
if (args == "") {
    // Write something to do here.
}
```

if you don't want it to do anything whe it equals to "", use:

```
if (args != null) {
   return "12345 - "+args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `=` with `==` in your if Statement:
Otherwise you are assigning an empty string to your `args` parameter.

```js
function test(args){
    if(args == ""){
    
    }
    return "12345 - "+args;
}
console.log(test("678910"));
```

Also your if doesn't do anything so the return will aways be `"12345 - "+args;`

If you only want to return, in case args is set do something like this:

```
if (args) {
    return "12345 - "+args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine ;)

```
   function test(args){
    if(args == ""){
    
    }
    return "12345 - "+args; }
    console.log(test("678910"));
```

Or you can use

```
    function test(args){
      if(args != null){
        return "12345 - "+args;
      }
    }
    console.log(test("678910"));
```